# Get user input without interrupting program execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm working on a program (a chat bot actually, you can see the code [here](https://github.com/RPiAwesomeness/BeamBot) if you want) that has an infinite loop running at all times.

I use `asyncio` as part of the code, so I initially tried creating another subroutine that received input and checked for commands. However, it didn't seem like that worked.

What I want to do is be able to issue the program commands without interrupting execution like using `input()` would. Preferably, it would have a `>` character and line that stays at the bottom of screen with the program output appearing above it and allows for input.

Is this possible to do with `asyncio` or do I need to look into multi-threading my program or something else?

**EDIT**: One thought I had was perhaps I could use an `ncurses` GUI-thing that has an entry field at the bottom and all the bot's output above the entry field. Would this be possible?

Comment: The [urwid](http://urwid.org/index.html) library supports using `asyncio` for its event loop, so it may work well for what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use asyncio since the StdIn is just another stream you can select...

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to do this? I'm new to doing multi-threaded/asynchronous programming :P

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have direct experience with the asyncio library. Generally speaking, there's often a function you can call to say "here are some IO streams. Please block until something interesting happens with them." One of those can be StdIn, some can be network streams, and I think there's one for SIG_ALRM so you can wake it up after a delay manually.

Answer (score -1):

```
from threading import Thread
import shlex


def endless_job():
    while True:
        pass


job = Thread(target=endless_job)
job.start()

while True:
    user_input = input('> ')
    print(shlex.split(user_input))
```

shlex module helps you to parse the command line entered by the user :)

If you need to pass arguments to the endless_job function, you can do something like:

```
job = Thread(target=endless_job, args=(1,'a'), kwargs={'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

where `args` and `kwargs` stands for positional and named arguments respectively.